# Multiple implementations for an AWS SWF activity or workflow interface in Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

I have an activity interface: `public interface BaseActivity`

My activity implementation is: `public class ABCActivity implements BaseActivity`

I would like to add a second activity implementation that also implements `BaseActivity`, like `public class DEFActivity implements BaseActivity`.

I would also like my activity worker to be able to process either of these activities.

From what I've been trying, this doesn't seem possible.

```
public interface BaseActivity {
    String activityMethod();
}

@Activities(version = 1.0", ...)
@ActivityRegistrationOptions( ... )
public interface ABCActivity extends BaseActivity {}

@Activities(version = 1.0", ...)
@ActivityRegistrationOptions( ... )
public interface DEFActivity extends BaseActivity {}
```

The `ABCActivityClient` and the `DEFActivityClient` that is generated doesn't contain `activityMethod`. Obviously, if I do:

```
@Activities(version = 1.0", ...)
@ActivityRegistrationOptions( ... )
public interface ABCActivity extends BaseActivity {
    String activityMethod()
}
```

Then it's all fine, but this kind of defeats the point of `BaseActivity`.

I think it's the same for the workflow interface and implementation.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

The reason I ask is because I would like to build multiple workflow implementations that have the same interface. These workflows will share some common activities (1 interface, 1 implementation), but also use some activities that have the same interface but different implementation (1 interface, multiple implementations).

Of course, I can just write out different interfaces for the "activities that have the same interface but different implementations:

`public interface ABCActivity`

`public class ABCActivityImpl implements ABCActivity`

`public interface DEFActivity`

`public class DEFActivityImpl implements DEFActivity`

Answer (score 0):

An activity interface defines not only the signature but also the the *activity type* and scheduling options of an activity. So by definition multiple implementations of an activity have to share the type and scheduling options defined through annotation. Because of that SWF wouldn't know which activity implementation to invoke. So what you want is not possible.

The standard workaround is to use a different task list for different activity implementations. This requires running a separate ActivityWorker per an activity implementation.

Another option is to use the DynamicActivityClient that allows specifying an activity type as a string. See the "Dynamic Clients" section from the [AWS Flow Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/clients.html)